# Dimensions of an Image - WebDav?

Tags: core-service, webdav, 2013-sp1-hr1

I've written a web application using core service which helps in getting the list of multimedia content along with the other info. My XML looks like below:

```
<tcm:Item ID="tcm:76-13941" Title=" ABC JPG" 
          Icon="T16L0P0Mjpg" Type="16" FromPub="Global Content" 
          IsNew="false" Modified="2015-11-03T19:37:30" 
          Size="2928" SchemaId="tcm:76-491-8" 
          WebDavUrl="\070 US\Building Blocks\Content\Multimedia\images\Author\ABC JPG" 
          BinaryName="ABC.jpg" >
```

Now I want to get the dimensions of the image. Unfortunately this info is not provided via metadata as part of mmc's Schema. So I have to probably get this from the physical file on webdav, if so should I use `GetExternalBinaryContentData`?

Env: 2013 Hr1

Comment: "my xml looks like below": xml is missing, please add. Also please suggest your requirement of why do you want to create application using webdav?

Comment: @Bart, thank  you for taking care of the xml..

Comment: That was Dominic Cronin before me actually ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest writing an event handler that captures the dimensions when the component is saved. You can choose to put this in a metadata field (if it makes sense to have the data visible to, or possibly altered by, the content people). Alternatively - if your core service application is the only user of the data, you might prefer to add it to the Application Data of the component. Then your application can just read it out.

If it's really necessary to do this via the core service (for example, to obtain the dimensions of existing items), then you can probably use IStreamDownload2013.DownloadBinaryContent

Comment: Writing an event handler/application data is a good option (which i already thought off, along with the MMC schema changes), but that will help only new ones.. There are like a zillion images already :( uploaded.. may be i have to let business know that its not possible with existing ones.

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: This looks like a good solution to read a single component.. in my case its a list of MM components thus, will be resource intensive. I will push my business to start inputing this data in meta.. Thanks everyone for your help..

Comment: You should also consider using both approaches. Events system as the main mechanism, but using a script to process all the existing components and add the data.

Comment: Yup, thank Dominic